# Graphic Design vs Writers: Which is best for designing a document?

Tags: discussion, design, specific-question, site-recommendation

These are two examples:

- [Is this a good way to present images and captions for research document?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35557/critique-is-this-a-good-way-to-present-images-and-captions-for-research-documen?noredirect=1#comment49264_35557)
- [Nice and elegant separation between proof/equations and explanation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35474/critique-nice-and-elegant-separation-between-proof-equations-and-explanation/35554#35554)

I am writing a thesis and I want it to be perfect and designed well. Should my questions belong to Graphic Design or Writers?

Personally I think Graphic Design is better because what I ask is *how to make a good looking document*, not *how to write a good thesis paper*. However I am not sure.

What do you think?

Comment: Yeah I know that, so that why this question is here.

Comment: Questions about graphics *in the context of a written document* (like a thesis, article, user manual, etc) are on-topic on Writers.  Whether they are also on-topic on GD I don't know.  Sometimes a question fits more than one site.  (Note, though, that neither site does "what do you think?" questions; those are too discussion-y.  Writers has critique guidelines, but in my experience it's better to ask "how do I meet such-and-such goal with my figures/equations/etc".